# Possibility of creating DAGs in Airflow

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Is there a way that one can make a DAG file dynamically from code and upload it on airflow(AirFlow reads from the dags directory, but creating file for every DAG and uploading it on that folder is slow)?

Is it possible to create a template dag and populate it with new logic whenever it is needed?

I saw that they are working on API. The current version only has a trigger DAG option.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily create multiple dags in a single file:

```py
create_dag(dag_id):
  dag = DAG(....)
  // some tasks added
  return dag

for dag_id in dags_lists:
  globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id)
```

If you create a proper DAG object with the template function (`create_dag` in the above example) and make them available in the globals object, Airflow will recognise them as individual DAGs.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create dynamic DAGs as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def create_dag(dag_id,
               schedule,
               dag_number,
               default_args):

    def hello_world_py(*args):
        print('Hello World')
        print('This is DAG: {}'.format(str(dag_number)))

    dag = DAG(dag_id,
              schedule_interval=schedule,
              default_args=default_args)

    with dag:
        t1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='hello_world',
            python_callable=hello_world_py,
            dag_number=dag_number)

    return dag


# build a dag for each number in range(10)
for n in range(1, 10):
    dag_id = 'hello_world_{}'.format(str(n))

    default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
                    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1)
                    }

    schedule = '@daily'

    dag_number = n

    globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id,
                                  schedule,
                                  dag_number,
                                  default_args)
```

Example from https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/

However, note that this can cause some issues like delays between the execution of tasks. This is because Airflow Scheduler and Worker will have to parse the entire file when scheduling/executing each task for a single DAG.

As you would have many DAGs (let's say 100) inside the same file this will mean that all the 100 DAG objects will have to be parsed while executing a single task for DAG1.

I would recommend building a tool that creates a single file per DAG.